# How to derive the electrical potential of a quadrupole ion trap (Paul trap)?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, ion-traps

Currently I am studying the behaviors of an ion in a quadrupole trap (Paul trap), but I just can’t understand that why the electrical potential of this trap is
\begin{equation}
\phi = \frac{U_0}{r_0^2}(\lambda x^2 +\sigma y^2+\gamma z^2)
\end{equation}
Where $U_0$ is the applied electrical voltage, $r_0$ is a geometry parameter and $\lambda, \sigma, \gamma $ are weighting factors, which are also determined by the geometry structure of the trap.

I searched on some papers and Wikipedia, but they just give out that potential directly with no derivation, so my question is how to derive that potential?

Comment: There is nice lecture by Paul on https://www.nobelprize.org/uploads/2018/06/paul-lecture.pdf

Comment: @AlexTrounev Actually I have read this paper, but I can’t understand where does $U_0$ and $r_0$ come from. Maybe you can give me another more elaborate lecture or paper? Thanks